# render the values of controllers to view

Tags: php

I am newbie to class and objects.Here I am making an application for invoice.So for the controllers as in the frameworks  I have taken them as handlers.So for the UserHandler
I have made this query:

```
<?php
class UserHandler {
  public $db;
  public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  public function index() {
    print_r($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nt_user"));
  }
 }
```

It is showing result in array as I want like that.

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => xyz [name] => xyz [2] => 5d6305f2 [password] => 5d6305f2 [3] => 2011-05-24 14:59:17 [created_at] => 2011-05-24 14:59:17 [4] => 2011-05-24 14:59:17 [updated_at] => 2011-05-24 14:59:17 )
```

Now I want to show that result in a view template.As view template is another file how to render all the values of handlers to the view.
I want the view page show like this:

```
name:
Password:
```

just like the login box.So please tell me how to do that?

Comment: are you using a particular framework or have you rolled your own?

Comment: Ya I am doing this only in php not any framwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static class using magic methods __get and __set to the the values like:

```
class Data {

    public static $atributos = array();

    public function __get($chave) {
        return array_key_exists($chave, $this->atributos) ? $this->atributos[$chave] : NULL;
    }

    public function __set($chave, $valor) {
        $this->atributos[$chave] = $valor;
    }

}
```

To set a value, you use: `Data::__set('view_data', $my_var);`

On the view you just do: `Data::__get('view_data');`

I think it will work =)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a particular framework or have you rolled your own? Zend Framework for instance would be like this.

```
<?php
class UserHandler extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public $db;
  public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  public function index() {
    $this->view->data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nt_user"));
  }
 }
```

And then in the view

```
<?php 
    //view.phtml
    var_dump($this->data);
```

This will give you the array dump that you have in your post. I'm not going to do the looping and displaying stuff though, I'm sure you can work that out yourself.